# Extract empty values from a .csv file into a new .csv file in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a product Master data set stored in a file called `TOB_Data.csv`. It contains data with the headers ‘Material ID’, ‘Material Description’, ‘Plant’, ‘Material Type’, ‘Laboratory Design office’, ‘Created on’, ‘Procurement Type’, ‘Product Line’, ‘Product Line Desc’, ‘Product Family’, ‘Product Family Desc’, ‘Product Type’, ‘Product Type Desc’, ‘Master Number’, ‘Master Number Desc’, ‘Colour Code’, ‘Colour Code Desc’, ‘PSG’, ‘PSG Desc’.

In this file there are some rows with empty values in the headers. For example

[image]

I would like to extract the rows with empty cells into a new `.csv` file

This is the code I have written

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("TOB_Data.csv")

mask = df.isnull().any(axis=1)

df[mask].to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

Where and what am I doing wrong here? This is not giving the output that I want.

Comment: From the `isnull` [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html): NA values, such as None or `numpy.NaN`, gets mapped to True values. Everything else gets mapped to False values. Characters such as empty strings `''` or `numpy.inf` are not considered NA values (unless you set `pandas.options.mode.use_inf_as_na = True`).